# How create a conditional type in typescript based on literal values?

Tags: typescript

I have the following definitions:

```
interface StreamDefinition<D> {
    parser: (data: Record<string, string>) => D | null;
    streamType: string;
    defaultStreamName: string;
    patternStream: boolean;
}

const aStreamDefinition: StreamDefinition<number> = {
    parser: (data) => parseInt(data['val']),
    streamType: 'streamA',
    defaultStreamName: 'data:A',
    patternStream: false,
};

const bStreamDefinition: StreamDefinition<string> = {
    parser: (data) => data['val'],
    streamType: 'StreamB',
    defaultStreamName: 'data:B:*:stream',
    patternStream: true,
};

export const streams = {
    A: aStreamDefinition,
    B: bStreamDefinition,
};
type StreamsDefinitions = typeof streams;
```

Now I am trying to generate a mapped conditional type based on `StreamDefinitions` type.
This new typer should be an object with every key that exists in streams const, but the value should be generated based on the following rules:

- if `patternStream` field is true then it should be a dictionary of generic type `D`: `{[key: string]: D}`
- if `patternStream` field is false then it should be the type itself `D`

here is an example of a valid object of this type:

```
const result = {
   A: 1,
   B: { x: "test", y: "test2"}
}
```

So far i've got this but it just assigns the dict to each key.

```
type FinalDataType = {
    [T in keyof StreamsDefinitions]: StreamsDefinitions[T]['patternStream'] extends false
        ? ReturnType<StreamsDefinitions[T]['parser']>
        : { [key: string]: ReturnType<StreamsDefinitions[T]['parser']> };
};};
```

Comment: So, I see three issues: **(1)** Your definitions of streams widen the type, resulting in `patternStream` always being `boolean`. **(2)** you are checking against `"true"` instead of `true`. **(3)** You have the cases back to front: if `patternStream` is `true`, it will resolve to just the type, which is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: ah yes, I was just experimenting with different things like switching from a boolean to a string to better inference but it didnt work. doing `extends false` which to me makes sense, always gives the same result. I'll edit the question to fix this.

Comment: Fixing those appears to work: [TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRAexW). Should I write up an answer, or have I missed something?

Comment: Oh it does work that way! How does that `check` function work? Is it required or just a shortcut?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the answer and accidentally deleted the draft... (closed VS Code tab instead of viewing preview) Coming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your definitions are using type annotations, which fix the type of the variable as the given type.
Because of this, `patternStream` is always `boolean` instead of `true` or `false`.

The main thing is to add a type parameter for it to `StreamDefinition`:

```js
interface StreamDefinition<Data, IsPatternStream extends boolean> {
  parser: (data: Record<string, string>) => Data | null;
  streamType: string;
  defaultStreamName: string;
  patternStream: IsPatternStream;
}

const streamDefinition: StreamDefinition<number, false> = {
  parser: (data) => parseInt(data["val"]),
  streamType: "streamX",
  defaultStreamName: "data:X",
  patternStream: false,
};
```

However, this is verbose: you have to specify the type parameters, which is unnecessary since they can be inferred from the value. This is especially useful if the return type of the parser function (`Data`) is complex.
The use case for these would be if you want specify them so that the value has to abide by the type, instead of letting the types of those properties be inferred.

The first step for improving this is to use `satisfies` instead of a type annotation:

```js
const streamDefinition = {
  parser: (data) => parseInt(data["val"]),
  streamType: "streamX",
  defaultStreamName: "data:X",
  patternStream: false,
} satisfies StreamDefinition<number, false>;
/*
const streamDefinition: {
  parser: (data: Record<string, string>) => number;
  streamType: string;
  defaultStreamName: string;
  patternStream: false;
}
*/
```

Because `satisfies` does not widen the type like an annotation, only checks assignability, you can use wider types for the type parameters:

```js
const streamDefinition = {
  parser: (data) => parseInt(data["val"]),
  streamType: "streamX",
  defaultStreamName: "data:X",
  patternStream: false,
} satisfies StreamDefinition<unknown, boolean>;
```

This lets the actually used types be inferred from the value, instead of needing to explicitly specify them.

However, we can improve it further by using default type parameters:

```js
interface StreamDefinition<
  Data = unknown,
  IsPatternStream extends boolean = boolean,
> {
  parser: (data: Record<string, string>) => Data | null;
  streamType: string;
  defaultStreamName: string;
  patternStream: IsPatternStream;
}

const streamDefinition = {
  parser: (data) => parseInt(data["val"]),
  streamType: "streamX",
  defaultStreamName: "data:X",
  patternStream: false,
} satisfies StreamDefinition
```

And this mostly resolves the original issue!

Pros:

- Types are inferred.
- Type parameters can still be explicitly specified if needed, such as to enforce a specific type for the parser return value.

Cons:

- The `| null` in the return type of the parser function is lost because the type is inferred form the function itself.
  If this is important, add a return type annotation to the parser function or use the function method instead.
- The type of the variable is the full object instead of the type name and parameters.
  If this is an issue for you, you can use the function method.

The cons boil down to it just checking assignability to the type instead of actually using it.

[TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVO5Gm)

---

If you cannot use `satisifes` (old TS version, old bundler version, etc.) or the cons are too great, you can use a helper function instead:

```js
interface StreamDefinition<Data, IsPatternStream extends boolean> {
  parser: (data: Record<string, string>) => Data | null;
  streamType: string;
  defaultStreamName: string;
  patternStream: IsPatternStream;
}

// You can use whatever name you like.
const stream = <Data, IsPatternStream extends boolean>(
  stream: StreamDefinition<Data, IsPatternStream>,
) => stream

const streamDefinition = stream({
  parser: (data) => parseInt(data["val"]),
  streamType: "streamX",
  defaultStreamName: "data:X",
  patternStream: false,
})
// const streamDefinition: StreamDefinition<number, false>
```

Pros:

- It works where `satisfies` is not available.
- The type of the variable is the type name and parameters instead of the full object.
- Using a short/single-character name for the function allows for very terse code.

Cons:

- It requires a function call for every definition. This should be very minor, though.

[TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBBdnN)